# C#: Download large sized json file from ADLS gen2 blob and Deserialize to object

Tags: c#, .net, azure, .net-core, azure-data-lake

I am using following code to output data from blob to stream.:

```
    private static async Task<Stream> ParallelDownloadBlobAsync(Stream outPutStream, CloudBlockBlob blob)
    {

        await blob.FetchAttributesAsync();
        int bufferLength = 1 * 1024 * 1024;//1 MB chunk
        long blobRemainingLength = blob.Properties.Length;
        Queue<KeyValuePair<long, long>> queues = new Queue<KeyValuePair<long, long>>();
        long offset = 0;
        while (blobRemainingLength > 0)
        {
            long chunkLength = (long)Math.Min(bufferLength, blobRemainingLength);
            queues.Enqueue(new KeyValuePair<long, long>(offset, chunkLength));
            offset += chunkLength;
            blobRemainingLength -= chunkLength;
        }
        Parallel.ForEach(queues, new ParallelOptions()
        {
            //Gets or sets the maximum number of concurrent tasks
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10
        }, (queue) =>
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                blob.DownloadRangeToStreamAsync(ms, queue.Key, queue.Value);
                lock (outPutStream)
                {
                    outPutStream.Position = queue.Key;
                    var bytes = ms.ToArray();
                    outPutStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }
            }
        });

        return outPutStream;
    }
```

Then i have used JsonSerializer to deseriize data but **while block is not executing**

```
 await ParallelDownloadBlobAsync(stream, cloudBlockBlob);

                //resetting stream's position to 0

                //stream.Position = 0;
                var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

                    using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
                        {
                            jsonTextReader.SupportMultipleContent = true;
                            result = new List<T>();


                            while (jsonTextReader.Read())
                            {
                                result.Add(serializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonTextReader));
                            }

                        }
                    }
```

> If i use **DownloadToStreamAsync**  instead of parallel download (**DownloadRangeToStreamAsync**) then
>   it works.

Comment: Could you please tell me the error message when you use ```DownloadRangeToStreamAsync```?

Comment: No error message but the code  result.Add(serializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonTextReader)); does not get execute as while condition is not satisfied

Comment: @SagarK, what's the size of the json file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can repro your issue, and the solution here is that in the `ParallelDownloadBlobAsync` method, change this line of code `blob.DownloadRangeToStreamAsync(ms, queue.Key, queue.Value);` to `blob.DownloadRangeToStream(ms, queue.Key, queue.Value);`

Not sure if the same root cause of the issue for you and me. In my side, the root cause is that when the file is small(like 100kb), when using `blob.DownloadRangeToStreamAsync` method, the output stream is always 0, so the `while condition` is never executed. But for larger files, it's ok to use `blob.DownloadRangeToStreamAsync` method.

Please leave a comment if it cannot resolve your issue.

Comment: i will check and let you know

Comment: Yes Ivan but i need to implement parallel blob download

Comment: i am using .net core and i do not find definition for DownloadRangeToStream

Comment: @SagarK, please let me know the which version of storage nuget package you're using. There're some changes in different storage nuget package.

Comment: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob version = 8.1.4.0

Comment: There is one more question i have added : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60218160/net-core-how-to-pass-parameters-and-run-azure-data-factory-pipeline-from-c-sh

Comment: @SagarK, the version you're using is too old, and it does not support sync method like `DownloadRangeToStream` in for .NET core project. Please use this version [Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob/), which does have sync method `DownloadRangeToStream` in for .NET core project.

Comment: Project has by default reference to package  Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob and is not visible under nuget folder

Comment: @SagarK, what do you mean "s not visible under nuget folder"? If possible, can you attach an screenshot about it:).

Comment: Need your expertise : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60874798/how-to-improve-performance-of-downloading-large-size-azure-blob-file-over-a-stre